# Preferred way of checking fulfilled forms in MVC and observer pattern

Tags: java, architecture, observer-pattern

I have an application in which the user can enter some data on a general user interface e.g. username, password, server url, ...
There is a button on this gui which triggers an `AbstractAction` which triggers the server model to start the server. This server model now fires a property change to the gui and this gui should now check the fields in the form if they are fullyfilled. If not, stop the whole action and get a message to the user.

So now my question is: Is this the preferred way of checking if a form was fullfilled? I wrote this code, but in my opinion this is a little bit confusing `(gui --> action -- > model --> gui --> model)`?!

Answer (score 0):

You should always validate the data sent to the server to prevent hacking, however there is no need to do the full loop for user interface level validation.

First at the UI layer validate the data, show a nice and dynamic display of anything that needs completing, is invalid etc.

Only once it passes that first level check do you want to send the data and then you validate it server side to make sure the client hasn't been tampered with/is bugged/etc.

Comment: And where do I check if the form was fullfilled? In the GUI or in it's corresponding ActionListener?

Comment: Your mention of server may have confused my answer as I thought you were talking about a distributed system. Personally I'd do the validation in either the controller or the model and update the GUI accordingly. The correct MVC architecture is view->controller->model->controller->view, and sometimes view->controller->view. In this case your controller is probably your ActionListener but in a complete system it is everything used to link your model and your view together.

Answer (score 0):

Validations like checking whether all the required fields are filled can be taken care by a controller since it does not require any idea about the business logic. Other validations which need an idea of the business logic can be taken care in the model which interacts with view via a controller. Validations on the client side (view) are generally considered not very secure (eg : using javascript).